# Winforms devexpress tile resize

Tags: winforms, resize, devexpress, tile

I dev WinForms w/ devexpress app, I want to resize and change the color of the tile in the group inside the tileBar.

I found no property to change size/color nor I could find any place to insert code inside C#.

```
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBar tileBar1;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarGroup tileBarGroup2;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarGroup tileBarGroup3;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem Refresh;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem2;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem4;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem3;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem5;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem6;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem7;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem8;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl gridControl1;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView1;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn StoreID;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn EnabledFrom;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn LastChanged;
    private DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn LastChangedBy;
    private DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem tileBarItem9;
```

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change a background color of a tile by using the **TileBarItem.AppearanceItem.Normal.BackColor** property.

TileBar supports items of two sizes: **medium** and **wide**. To manage height of a medium tile, use the [TileBar.ItemSize](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBar.ItemSize) property. To change width of a wide tile, use the [TileBar.WideTileWidth](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBar.WideTileWidth) property. To specify if your tile should be medium or wide, use the [TileBarItem.ItemSize](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Navigation.TileBarItem.ItemSize) property.